# Angular 2 - Create Component Dynamically - Is it mandatory to call 'detach()' method on the component reference?

Tags: angularjs, angular, components

I have an Angular 2 app where I need to create child components dynamically.

Is it mandatory to call '**detectChanges()**' and  '**detach()**' method on the component reference variable 'componentRef.changeDetectorRef' ?

I see things work properly even if I dont use them.

Are these methods are actually meant component injection performance improvement ?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'container',
    template: '<template #content></template>'
})
export class ContainerComponet implements AfterViewInit {
    contentComponentRef:any;
    @ViewChild('content', {read: ViewContainerRef}) contentHandle;

    constructor(private componentResolver:ComponentResolver) {
        super();
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() { 
        if (this.contentComponentRef)
           this.contentComponentRef.destroy(); 

    this.componentResolver.resolveComponent(ChildComponent)
      .then((factory:ComponentFactory<any>) => {
          let componentRef = this.contentHandle.createComponent(factory);

          componentRef.instance['child_component_property'] = 'dummy value for child';

          componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
          componentRef.onDestroy(() => {
              componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detach();
          });
          this.contentComponentRef = componentRef;
          return componentRef;
     });
    }    

}
```